# Removing oil filter from Lincoln Mark VIII

Tags: lincoln, mark-viii

I've had two different Lincoln Mark VIIIs - one 1993, and currently one 1996 LSC.  Both are "first generation" ('93-'96) Mark VIIIs, but I'm fairly certain this will also apply to "second generation" ('97-'98) models.

The problem is that the oil filter is in one of the most inconvenient places ever conceivable.  Usually, with *relatively* little trouble, I can get my arm in well enough to unscrew and pull the filter off.  But, when it comes to actually getting the filter out from the confined space that is its home, there always seems to be some form of creative contortionism required and I can never seem to remember how it is I got the thing out the last time.

Is there any "easy way" to go about doing this?  Is there some trick or special technique I might be missing out on?

Comment: I did an oil change and filter change in my '95 mark VIII. I found out that the BOSCH filter that the wife got me was approx. 1/2 inch fatter than the FRAM filter I had on it. Of course she got it from Mahalo Zone, from on of the tech at the counter. The FRAM filter came out with little difficulty, a little contortionism and viola. Unfortunately there was no possible way I could even get close to getting the BOSCH back in there without ripping the outside of the filter when forcing it back into the area. Of course I didn't force it, but now she is on her way back to the store to get me the FRA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had the pleasure of working on this model, and the service software I have doesn't give me a good picture of the situation. However, here are a couple of approaches to problematic oil filters (same applies to other parts as well):

- Does turning the wheel all the way (or part way) in one direction or the other cause the steering linkage to move out of the way? (I have found evidence that a hard right may work for this specific model).
- Can you access the filter from above? A number of components are surprisingly accessible from the top side of the engine, even if they are pretty far down.
- Does removing the driver side wheel (and associated wheel well trim) provide better access? If so, it's a matter of whether removing the wheel is more trouble than it's worth.

Please verify if the hard right turn is true for this model.

Comment: I seem to recall reading elsewhere that a hard turn will help.  I'll try to come back and update the next time I have a chance to test this.  The oil filter is most definitely not accessible from above, and I'm pretty sure removal of the wheel and trim offers little to no benefit in this situation for this vehicle.  Thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I can sympathize - ill-located greasy oil filters are a pain to get off. A few tips.

1. use the FRAM filters that have the grippy/rubberized surface designed to give your fingers some purchase upon removal.
2. try a combination of oil filter wrenches (the ones designed to go into a 3/8" drive ratchet) and extensions, u-joints, etc if space permits.
3. get one of those rubber non-slip mats designed to line drawers and wrap it around the oil filter one or more times. This will give you a decent bit of grip to power the filter off.
4. if you're so inclined, get a remote oil filter relocation kit.  This is an adapter with some oil lines that will let you mount the oil filter some place more convenient.  As an added bonus, a lot of these kits will let you mount a much larger oil filter as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  However, only #4 is really applicable to my problem.  (I'll have to find out if that's even possible, or advisable for my car.)  I can generally get the filter disconnected with relatively little trouble - it's actually getting it *out* that's the problem.